# Pickle file is clean after program restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, pickle

I use Heroku. When I save a file with `pickle`, all work fine, but after program restart the file is clean. I use these two methods

```
@staticmethod
def save_obj(obj, name):
    with open(f'plugins/utils/obj/{name}.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)

@staticmethod
def load_obj(name):
    with open(f'plugins/utils/obj/{name}.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

In the following way

```
if cmd[1] == 'b':  # add in dict
    bought = Utils.load_obj('bought')
    print(bought)
    bought[msg.user_id] = {'RU': {}}
    print(bought)
    Utils.save_obj(bought, 'bought')
elif cmd[1] == 'i':  # create empty dict
    Utils.save_obj({}, 'bought')
elif cmd[1] == 's':  # print all from dict
    print(Utils.load_obj('bought'))
```

Comment: What is minimum code to replicate the error that you encounter?

Comment: Before this, I create an empty dictionary. Other code above

Comment: Come on, that is the whole idea - provide the code that you have, and tell where the problem is, making it https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You read 'bought' and save 'b'. How is 'bought' created? Is 'b' empty?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku's filesytem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it are lost when your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). In addition, dynos can be restarted manually which you appear to be doing here.

Heroku [recommends storing uploads on something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), but depending what you're saving a client-server database might be a better solution. Heroku [supports many](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) and should provide you with a [PostgreSQL database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) out of the box. You can access it via the [`DATABASE_URL` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#designating-a-primary-database).

Comment: How do I get a file and do something with it?

Comment: @Nix13, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. How do you open the file up after you've saved it? You can use whatever S3 library you used to save the file in the first place, or if you set up permissions properly you may be able to retrieve it over HTTP. But if you're trying to save application data I really recommend using a database instead.

Comment: A database does not fit.